# Kubuntu not picking up extender

Tags: networking, wireless, kubuntu

Got a problem with kubuntu with not being able to connect to the Wi-Fi at times. It seems to be off and on but that it just due to the modem's signal performance.

The issue is that while I have an extender much closer to my PC, all the OS can see is a feint signal (~4% at worse) and so will be unable to connect to the internet/Wi-Fi. I'd like to know how to get kubuntu to recognize its existence.

It's not a problem with the extender or the adapter as both my phone and windows on the same PC work just fine. 
Hope you have some ideas, and thanks in advance.

EDIT: I may have been getting the same problem in Arch linux a few weeks ago that I was never able to solve the problem too there either...if that helps any.

EDIT2: So after using it for a while now, I've picked up some things. Downtime - when I cannot connect - is about 7:00-9:00 (Our ISP is popular and rubbish, but cheap, so I hope that explains enough). This is when connecting actually becomes a problem, the rest of the time it's fine...mostly. The adaptor also seems to find the extender momentarily at times, the speed decreases a bit, and that connection is dropped immediately after in favour of the faster direct connection (I do not know if this is the true reason). The issue is that when I can't connect to the modem directly, it will never find my extender and so I can't even get a slower connection.

Another question I have is why does signal strength get weaker when our ISP is under more load, I am under the presumption that should only affect speed, not our devices' connection strength...

Comment: Run this long command in terminal and edit your question to include URL `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info && cat wireless-info.txt | nc termbin.com 9999`

Comment: Unable to resolve host (github.com).

Comment: I am connected right now and I'll add some useful info to the OP.